# Frequent changes on attributes, is it wise to use Directory Service

Tags: opendj

I am trying to design a access solution using opendj, down the line i realized system will have frequent changes on accounts, users in the tree.
With your experience dealing with Open DJ / Directory Service is it wise to manage frequent changes and bulk changes .

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define frequent.

But OpenDJ / ForgeRock Directory Services have been designed to be able to deal with a larger throughput of updates than traditional directory servers. On our lab machines we're able to sustain 15 000 modifications per seconds on a single server in a replicated environment that is up to date in milliseconds.